# ERROR in node_modules/@types/googlemaps/reference/event.d.ts(74,76): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular6

I'm building project in Angular 6 and trying to add google map to my web site.
But on ng serve getting:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/googlemaps/reference/event.d.ts(74,76): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/googlemaps/reference/info-window.d.ts(8,21): error TS1122: A tuple type element list cannot be empty.
```

Can't find how to solve this problem. I tried to change "@types/googlemaps" version to "^3.26.15" - the same error.
package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/rx": "^4.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    }),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'here I set my api key'
    })
  ],
```

google-map.component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]='latitude' [longitude]='longitude' [mapTypeId]='mapType'>
</agm-map>
```

google-map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-map',
  templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {
  latitude = 32.083025;
  longitude = 34.792626;
  mapType = 'satellite';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Also I added in tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json

```
"types": [ "googlemaps"]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar error:

```
@types/googlemaps/reference/info-window.d.ts(73,71): error TS2304.
```

I soved it changing `@types/googlemaps` version based `typescript` version in my project.
In this [site](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/@types/googlemaps) you can see compatibility between `@types/googlemaps` and `typescript` version:

Comment: Link no longer works so this answer isn't very helpful.